# "Da brat' mir einer einen Storch!" - Herkunft?

Tags: meaning, etymology, proverb

Im Sinne eines Ausrufs wie "Ist ja ein dickes Ding!" oder "Unglaublich!". Die Redewendung ist vielleicht etwas aus der Mode.

[Hier](https://www.swr.de/wissen/1000-antworten/kultur/1000-Antworten-Was-bedeutet-da-brat-mir-einer-einen-Storch,1000-antworten-720.html) wird sie auf alttestamentarische Speisevorschriften zurückgeführt, den Storch soll man nicht essen, aber das saure Brot und das Schwein landen ja ohne weitere Vorbehalte auf dem Tisch und die gehören m.Wn. irgendwie auch dazu.

[Hier](https://www.geo.de/geolino/redewendungen/5061-rtkl-redewendung-da-brat-mir-einer-einen-storch) wird germanische Mythologie herangezogen, der Storch bringt den Nachwuchs, den soll man nicht vertreiben und schon gar nicht braten.

Möglicherweise gibt's weitere Erklärungen? Die beiden stellen mich nicht so recht zufrieden, wirken weit hergeholt, irgendwie sehe ich einen Widerspruch in Essen und Nachwuchs bzw. religiöse Vorschriften und Mythologie.

Weiß jemand mehr oder hat bessere Quellen als eine schnelle Internetsuche ?

"Well somebody fry me a stork!" is a German exclamation of surprise. I found 2 explanations, regulations about forbidden food from Old Testament or stork as a baby bringer that shouldn't be driven away (or eaten) from Germanic mythology. I find neither particularly satisfying. Maybe somebody here knows more about the origin of that saying?

Edit: Ich habe eine [dritte Erklärung](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=da%20brat%20mir%20einer%20einen%20Storch&bool=relevanz&sp0=rart_ou) gefunden die weniger direkt auf Mythologie zurückgreift und mir plausibler klingt. Demnach wurde der Storch im ausgehenden Mittelalter noch abergläubisch verehrt, und er galt als ungenießbar. "Gebratener Storch" = unerhört. Das klingt mir näherliegender als Altes Testament und Germanische Mythen.

Comment: Wenn der Storch, wie die Quellen angeben, als unantastbares Wesen angesehen wurde, kann es sein, dass die Redewendung auf folgendem Räsonieren basiert: "Das hört sich absolut unglaublich an, und ich halte daran fest. Derjenige, der das felsenfest behauptet, soll bereit sein, etwas Frevelhaftes zu tun, falls seine Behauptung nicht stimmt"?

Comment: Klar, kann man nicht ausschließen. Ich hoffe nur auf eine näher liegende Herleitung.

Comment: Was meinst du damit? Redewendungen basieren meistens auf Analogien, Schlussfolgerungen etc.

Comment: Unglaublich! - eben genauso wie wenn sich einer einen Storch briete. Die bringen ja die Babys. Das ist provokant, aber nicht allzu grob, es wird ja vieles verspeist. Man zieht die Aufmerksamkeit, ja Empörung auf sich und kann die dann auf die Story umlenken. Wer hat den Spruch erfunden, das wäre die Frage. (ausser diesem Anonymus)

Comment: @rastafile Was hat das mit "Babys" zu tun?

Comment: Fruchtbarkeitssymbol vielleicht hat mit Babys zu tun, es wird doch erklärt in deinem Link. Der Storch übergibt die Neugeborenen. Trägt sie in einem Tuch im Schnabel direkt aufs Dach, sozusagen.

Comment: @rastafile Ich bin mir gar nicht so sicher ob das mit dem Klapperstorch und dem kleinen Bündel im Schabel nicht ein Bild des 19. Jahrhunderts ist und evtl. gar nix mit dem Spruch zu tun hat.

Comment: Klar, das Bild ist vom 19. Jh. oder so, aber das greift nur diesen alten, nicht eruierbaren Mythos auf. Wie der Weihnachtsbaum und das Osterei bzw. -hasen. Der Spruch muss ja überhaupt nicht alt sein. Ich finde das ist die gelungene Steigerung von "Ich glaube mich laust der Affe!". Das möchte man ja auch nicht einfach so, ohne Ankündigung...

Comment: Ich würde auf Verbalhornung eines ursprünglich anders lautenden Spruchs tippen, insofern der Spruch erhebliches Alter hätte, und dann wäre auch klar, dass es heute keinen Sinn mehr ergibt. Über die den Faden nicht abbeißende Maus findet man auch unterschiedliches; ein wirklich vergleichbarer Spruch mit scheinbarem Imperativ zum Ausdruck der Überraschung fällt mir auf die Schnelle nicht ein (wäre sicherlich hilfreich)--bspw. *?Ich fress'n Besen* (Thema: Essen)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Das Deutsche Wörterbuch von Grimm & Grimm sagt zu diesem Spruch (weit unten im Lemma "Storch"):

> α) scherzhaft als ausdruck einer starken verwunderung *da brat mir einer einen storch!* in dem sinne von 'so etwas ist noch nicht erlebt, noch nicht dagewesen! da hört doch alles auf!' und mit dem weiteren zusatze *und (aber) die beine (beene) recht knusperig!* vgl. MÜLLER-FRAUREUTH 2, 569a: wohl übernommen aus der anderen wendung
>   *du kannst mir einen storch braten, aber die beene recht knusperig* 'du kannst mir gewogen bleiben', angesichts der knorpeligen, dürren storchbeine eine steigerung des ungenieszbaren (auch allein *du kannst mer en storch braten!* als verächtlicher zuruf MÜLLER-FRAUREUTH a. a. o.). — in Sachsen auch als antwort für einen unberufenen frager *geschmulter (geschmorter) storch* ALBRECHT Leipz. ma. 218a; ähnlichen sinn hat *vertell mî nuscht vom storch sîne hinderbêne* FRISCHBIER sprichw. 2, 175, d. h. 'bring nichts widersinniges, unglaubliches vor'.

(Bd. 19, Sp. 371 ff., hier kopiert aus: http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GS49073#XGS49073)<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>DWB = Deutsches Wörterbuch von Jacob und Wilhelm Grimm. 16 Bde. in 32 Teilbänden. Leipzig 1854-1961. Quellenverzeichnis Leipzig 1971.

Comment: Sehr schön, Grimm's Wörterbuch im Netz, wußte ich gar nicht. Da wird auch auf die Ungenießbarkeit angespielt.

Comment: @a_donda  Ja... aber wo diese Idee der Ungenießbarkeit der Störche im Mittelalter nun herkam, wird auch nicht erwähnt. Irgendwas aus der populären Theaterkulter, Liederkultur, Jahrmarktskultur vielleicht? Und kommt das in anderen Sprachen auch vor? Ich glaube, man könnte ein Doktorarbeit drüber schreiben.

Comment: Ich hab' mal Schwan probiert. Da muß der Hunger schon sehr, sehr groß sein ...

Comment: @a_donda  Vielleicht war er nicht richtig zubereitet?

Comment: Leck mich einer am Allerwertestest, mit so einer guten Antwort hät ich nicht gerechnet.

Answer (score 1):

Die Erklärungen hinken alle. Ich habe auf *redensarten-index.de* diese Definition gefunden:

> ***umgangssprachlich, salopp;*** Nach einer biblischen Speisevorschrift Q
>   darf der Storch (ebenso wie Fledermaus oder Reiher) nicht gegessen
>   werden. Dies **übertrug** sich auch auf das Mittelalter, **zudem** der Storch
>   abergläubische Verehrung genoss und sein Fleisch als ungenießbar **galt**.

Dieses ***zudem*** ist elegant, bedeutet aber hier: *vielleicht auch*.

Da kommt schon alles zusammen, aber in einem naiven Narrativ.

Die AT Speisevorschrift beinhaltet ja sehr viele Tiere, auch Schweine. Das hat mit dem christlichen Mittelalter nicht direkt zu tun.

> Nur scherzhaft wird der Storch daher in der Literatur der Renaissance
>   gelegentlich als **Leckerbissen** genannt.

Was heisst "nur scherzhaft"! Gerade deswegen, als humorvolle Provokation.

Herkunft von was genau? Storchen-Mythos oder Redewendung?

Comment: Danke, yep, die hatte ich schon verlinkt im OP ...

Comment: Und was willst du wissen? Wieso genau der Storch in Europa seit jeher als besonders gilt? Oder was die Quelle für diese Redewendung ist? Das sind doch zwei Paar Schuhe.

Comment: Wo die Redewendung herkommt. Obwohl die Vorstellung von Q wie er theatralisch vor Moses erscheint auch ganz nett ist. Völlig abwegiger Gedanke :-)

Answer (score 0):

Der Storch ist oft auf Schornsteinen/Kaminen/Rauchfängen angesiedelt, wo er ein großes Nest baut. In der Zeit der Brutpflege sind die Jungen im Nest und die Altvögel wechseln ständig zwischen Nahrungssuche und Brutpflege. In dieser Zeit sollte man nicht einheizen, zumal die Gefahr bestünde, dass die Jungvögel durch die ausströmende Heißluft richtiggehend gebraten würden. "Da brat mir einer einen Storch" würde ich eher interpretieren als "Konjunktiv der Befürchtung", dass jemand (unbeabsichtigt) etwas in die Wege leiten könnte (z.B. Einheizen eines Ofens), was dann zu einem verheerenden Ergebnis führt (z.B. Vertreiben der Störche oder Töten der Jungstörche durch austretende Gase).
Ich glaube, diese Redewendung stammt aus der reinen praktischen Lebenserfahrung mit Storchennestern/Storchenpopulationen und man sollte gerade die Leute in den Orten, wo Störche Nestbau betreiben, mit dieser Redewendung konfrontieren (in Niederösterreich und im Burgenland gäbe es einige Orte).

Comment: Ist das Spekulation bzw. eigene Schlussfolgerung, oder hast Du Quellen dafür?

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Inwiefern stellt " man sollte gerade die Leute in den Orten, wo Störche Nestbau betreiben, mit dieser Redewendung konfrontieren" Teil der Antwort dar? Soll es heißen, dass jegliche Orte, in denen Storchennester zum Alltag gehören, diese Redewendung erklären können sollten? Das wären allein in Deutschland ziemlich viele...

Answer (score 0):

Meine Erklärungen beruhen genauso auf reiner Spekulation wie die anderen Theorien. Meines Erachtens hat bisher noch niemand eine mit wissenschaftlichen Mitteln nachweisbare Erklärung geliefert, wie es zu dieser Redewendung kam.
Meines Wissens war der Storch in allen Kulturen ein geschützter heiliger Vogel und wäre dessen Erlegung und Verspeisung etwas wie ein Gottesfrevel gewesen (vergleichbar etwa mit dem Ibis im antiken Ägypten). "Da brat mir einer einen Storch" kann ich daher nicht als Aufforderung oder als Wunsch, ein unter göttlichem Schutz stehendes Tier zu verspeisen, verstehen, vielmehr sehe ich das eher als Befürchtung, jemand könnte (unabsichtlich) diesem heiligen Tier Leid zufügen. Das "brat" sehe ich eindeutig als Konjunktiv (Langform:brate) im Sinne von "Behüte Gott, dass jemals der Fall eintreten könnte, dass jemand einen Storch (zu Tode) braten könnte" - als Abwehr und Abwendung eines solchen Gottesfrevels.
Mein Vorschlag, man sollte die Leute in den Orten, wo regelmäßig Störche brüten, befragen, ist Teil der Antwort. Ich glaube nämlich wirklich, dass diese Redewendung aus dem echten Leben stammt (aus früheren Jahrhunderten, wo die Leute abergläubischer als heute waren und mit Storchennestern konfrontiert waren, die direkt auf dem Rauchfang/Schornstein von Häusern gebaut wurden). Das hatte zur Folge, dass man, während die Horste besetzt waren, nicht einheizen durfte (auch das Räuchern/Selchen war dann nicht möglich). Ich kann mir vorstellen, dass es Leute gab, die das nicht so genau nahmen, und trotz noch nicht flugfähiger Jungvögel einheizten - mit verheerenden Folgen. Meine Theorie ist die, dass in den Orten, wo vielleicht schon seit Jahrhunderten Störche auf diversen Schornsteinen brüten, dass deren hauptsächlich aus Astholz bestehende Nester (in Österreich sagt man dafür auch Horste) regelmäßig von den Hausbesitzern entfernt werden, wenn die Horste nicht mehr besetzt sind (sonst ist nämlich der Luftzug zwischen Ofen und Schornstein nicht mehr gegeben, weil eben die Kaminöffnung durch Holz blockiert ist, und könnte man nicht mehr richtig einheizen). Beim Entfernen der Horste mag man auf tote Storchenjungvögel gestoßen sein und habe diese auf das verfrühte Einheizen zurückgeführt (die Störche werden wohl eher durch Rauchgase als durch die entweichende Heißluft gestorben sein, aber man wird das "Braten" als Todesursache angenommen haben).
Zur Untermauerung meiner Theorie schlage ich vor, da es in der BRD ziemlich viele Städte zu geben scheint, wo Storchennester zum Alltag gehören, dass dort hauptsächlich ältere Leute befragt werden, wie die Bevölkerung früher mit den Störchen und deren Nestern umging und wie das "Da brat mir einer einen Storch" gedeutet werden könnte.
Weiters möchte ich noch anregen, Experten aus dem Bereich der Sprachwissenschaft zu befragen, aus welcher Zeit diese Redewendung stammen und wie sie etymologisch gedeutet werden könnte.
Da ich diese Redewendung trotz meines Alters bisher noch nie hörte, scheint mir deren Ursprung eher im bundesdeutschen Sprachraum zu liegen. Ich werde aber in Österreich, wo es namhafte Storchenpopulationen gibt, Nachforschungen anstellen, ob jemandem diese Redewendung bekannt ist und ob jemand Aufschluss über deren Bedeutung liefern kann.
Ich jedenfalls finde die Sache voll interessant und spannend.

Comment: Willkommen! Hattest Du schon die Gelegenheit, Sich durch die [tour] und das [help] zu klicken? [answer] ist auch ganz hilfreich. Abgesehen davon, bitte beachte, dass alle Stack Exchange Seiten ein ganz spezielles Format haben: Eine Frage oben, nur Antworten darunter. Wobei jede Antwort eigenständig sein sollte, also statt neuer Antwort einfach die bestehende per [edit] anpassen.